# Django admin change_form with ajax query

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, admin

I'm working with an ModelAdmin from my model. I have a field that I need to 
check if it's right.

It's a string and I'm sending it to the server, and this returns me a graph in which I can check the string if it's ok.

The big question is about how to use ajax with the admin view, and 
the view returns the object to me.
It's a little different from the classic way with ajax+views, because i have the admin mode class inside admin.py.
I redefined the change_form template and added the js and ajax calls. But it returns me nothing at the moment.

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your change_form.html in the below hierachy:

```
/myproject/templates/admin/myapp/mymodel/change_form.html
```

And inherit the base change_form.html from admin.
Eg:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% block after_field_sets %}{{ block.super }}
Print my model here {{ original }}
Print foreignkey related records of my model:
{% for item in original.items_set.all %} {{ item }} {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Yeah, i had that. But the question it's about where i put the action view with the ajax request. I an independant view or inside the admin class?

Comment: you can handle this in independent view for your ajax calls, that view will be responsible for the required data by ajax

Comment: @DavidPinedaOsorio always ready to help, please upvote and accept as the correct answer.

Comment: Yep, i voted, but i have less than 15 points or something like that :)